# Return to same ViewComponent from Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `ViewComponent` embedded within a page. In this component I have a form that submits to a controller action.

The index page contains:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("ValidateOrder")
    </div>
</div>
```

The view component just returns the view:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    return View();
}
```

And the component's view:

```
<form asp-antiforgery="true" asp-area="Customer" asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Validate" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" />
            <small>
                <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-style-1 btn-primary">Check</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And finally, the controller's action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Validate(ValidateOrderViewModel model)
{
    if (!TryValidateModel(model))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    
    var result = await orderService.ValidateAsync(model.Number);
    return View(result); //How to return back to the view component?
}
```

I need to return the action's result back to the same component.

I tried to return `View`, `RedirectToAction`, `ViewComponent` and even `Json`. But nothing is working as expected.

This the only alternative to redirect to the page and pass the result in `ViewData`?

Comment: Put the code example here, what are you doing and how?

Comment: validation can be handled on posting the form.  (.net has built-in client-side and backend validation)  In razor pages it's just:   if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return Page(); }  Otherwise you return RedirectToPage()  To a details page or something like that.

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0